# Tool to monitor and log a single HTTP connection on Linux?

Tags: linux, http

We're trying to debug an issue with a server that must receive and respond to a large number of persistent HTTP connections.

Ideally we'd like a tool that could pick (at random) a single HTTP connection and log all traffic to and from it, such that we can see what is going on.

Unfortunately we don't have the ability to limit the number of persistent connections we must respond to (typically it is thousands of them), so we really need to tool to narrow down its monitoring to just a single connection.

Can anyone recommend such a tool, and give guidance on how to persuade it to do what we need?

Comment: “Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it.” Reference: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 3):

Wireshark is a great open source tool for this purpose.

Comment: Can it run on a headless server?  Are you sure it can meet our needs (by selecting just a single persistent connection to monitor)?

Comment: It does require a GUI, if you don't want to run something like VNC (Remote Desktop) on the headless server, is use tcpdump along with the filtering rules it provides to capture a specific conversation into a file, then load the cap file into Wireshark on a workstation for easier analysis.

Comment: The problem is that I don't know the specific conversations in advance, tcpdump would need to identify the conversation it wants to watch on the fly (everything happens quite quickly, it takes just a few seconds to get up to thousands of concurrent HTTP connections :-/ )

Comment: Well if the requirement is randomly selecting, write a script to randomly select a specific HTTP connection and log it to the file.  Either that or pick a window during the day you'd want to capture, then review those connections.  The other option is to log all HTTP connections and review randomly later.

Answer (score 0):

If using wireshark directly doesn't work out, you could fiddle with the routing on a firewall/router type box and have the monitored connection go out over a different interface (where you can tap into it using wireshark or whatever) than all the rest of the connections to the server.

Answer (score 0):

The actual capturing of packets is usually done by `libpcap`.
There are different tools building on top of it:

- First there is good old `tcpdump`. It is a text tool, which allows you to specify what packets you are interested in and prints (per default) a line for each matching packet. Actually you have lots of option what shall be done. You can also dump all traffic in a capture file.
- Then there is `wireshark` (formerly known as ethereal). This is a GUI allowing you to capture packets as in tcpdump, and has lots of ways to analyze such data. It can also read and analyze capture files created by tcpdump.
- Along with wireshark comes `tshark` (formerly known as tethereal), which is pretty much the console version of wireshark.
- If you are only interested in the data send in the packets have a look at `tcpflow`.

There are also some more advanced tools which can also be used to attack other hosts.
For example `ettercap`, will list all current connections and among others can show you the data send on that connection.

It is not completely clear from your question, what exactly you try to find out, but it sounds like something like `tcpflow` might be what you want.